# Spring 3.0 Disable @Inject Annotation Processing

Tags: java, spring, cdi

Is there a way to disable the `@Inject` annotation processing of spring 3.0?

I'm trying to use the CDI `@Conversation` Scope together with spring, but when it comes to

```
@Inject
private Conversation conversation;
```

spring tries to autowire the conversation which obviously failed.

Comment: Curious to know Which CDI implementation did you use with Spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can. But spring has its own conversation support - take a look at spring web flow.

Comment: I've evaluated spring web flow but it seems to be a little out of scope by the spring community. The current mile stone plan is not updated since a year.

Comment: that's because a separate conversation support is planned to go into spring-mvc

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar problem when trying to mix Spring 3.x and CDI annotations.

I found a way to disable Spring `@Inject` processing in non Spring beans; simply create an exclude filter for classes annotated with `@Named`:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {@Filter(Named.class)})
public class SpringConfig
{
}
```

or disable default filters something like:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(useDefaultFilters = false, includeFilters = {@Filter(Component.class)})
public class SpringConfig
{
}
```

This works because Spring sets by default an include filter for `javax.inject.Named` to activate JSR-330 processing.