# Override default AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor to stop JSR-330 support

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring boot auto-config supports JSR-330 javax.inject.Inject annotation if available at classpath. I want to stop this cos it throws NPE when working with javax.enterprise.event.Event at CDI.

This is done because Spring auto register 4 defaults BeanPostProcessings, and AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor deals with @Autowired and @Value. But also inspect classpath to register @Inject.

Error sample:

```java
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class FormMB implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    private Event<MyEvent> myEvent;
[...]
}
```

raises the exception:

```java
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type javax.enterprise.event.Event<MyEvent>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
```

Digging deeper I found that JSR-330 `@Inject` annotation are included as an `autowiredAnnotationTypes` when present in classpath by `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` of Spring. 
Any suggestion to stop Spring from trying to Autowire `@Inject` annotations or, at least, to stop him from autowire `javax.enterprise.event.Event`
Tried this: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673856/spring-3-0-disable-inject-annotation-processing) but no success.

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
        this.autowiredAnnotationTypes.add(Autowired.class);
        this.autowiredAnnotationTypes.add(Value.class);
        try {
            this.autowiredAnnotationTypes.add((Class<? extends Annotation>)
                    ClassUtils.forName("javax.inject.Inject", AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class.getClassLoader()));
            logger.info("JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            // JSR-330 API not available - simply skip.
        }
    }
```

So I would like to override AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor, I`ve been able to include my own BeanPostProcessor like:

```java
SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(AppConfig.class);
        application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
        MyAutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor autowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor = new MyAutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
        autowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(application.run().getBeanFactory());
```

Comment: Just exclude `@Named` components from being detected in your component scanning. Or exclude the `javax.inject` dependency that will also disable the detection. However what is weird is that you get a `NullPointerException` because actually you should be getting an unstartable application because the injection point cannot be satisfied.

Comment: Ok, done that and keep contexts isolated, one for JEE things, and other for Spring functionalities. So that I can use `@Inject` inside `@Named`. But if I need to use `@Inject Event` inside a `@Component` the problem remains. Any suggestion?

Comment: Spring won’t inject `Event` as it doesn’t know anything about that. You might be able to get it to work by using a Spring-CDI bridge (there are 2 or 3 out there) but not sure. Also isn’t it weird that you want to use CDI events in a Spring component...